# Word sounding like “you-know-a-theme” and meaning something like “prudence”

Tags: listening, australian-english

This is probably best suited to the dedicated chatroom, but unfortunately I don’t have enough rep to enter it.

There’s a word  that I don’t understand in a formal speech in a youtube video.
The word is pronounced at around  5:30, and the URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8XzgPJdx2M#t=5m30s
Here is my transcript of the passage around it,  with the word that I don’t get in boldface :

> It’s not judgementalism at all. It’s quite the opposite. It’s
>    **you-know-a-theme** 
>   and it says you must flee the source of danger

The speaker is from Australia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I transcribed it:

> So, Robert Ballamine tells us we're obliged to avoid heretics. Judging that someone is a heretic and we're obliged to avoid them is not judgementalism at all. It's quite the opposite—it's **humility**. And it says, "I must flee this source of danger."

The word in question is *humility*, as you can see. Do you think you can hear it now? And also, I'm not at all sure how to spell the guy's last name that he mentions at the beginning of this passage. One thing that's clear though is that it begins with a "b". So, I just spelled it the way I heard it.

Comment: I would never have figured that out unless I had to watch the entire thing in hopes that they say it again somewhere, but more clearly.

Comment: I do hear "humility" now that you've told me, but what I hear is still Hu - NO -ity rather than Hu - mil -ity. I'm curious as to how you would transcribe the sounds in the word

Comment: I don't know how I would transcribe that. I just hear the word and it makes sense in the context he's speaking in.